# Using Mallet on Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, mallet

I've been using Cygwin on Windows for a POSIX environment.

When using the MALLET toolkit, however, I run into problems finding the classes. For example:

```
$bin/mallet import-file

Error: Could not find or load main class cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors
```

I tried wrapping the classpath in the bash script with `` `cygpath -pw $cp` `` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that java on Windows expects semi-colons, rather than colons.

Edit line 7 of `/bin/mallet` from:

```
cp=$malletdir/class:$malletdir/lib/mallet-deps.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

To:

```
cp="$malletdir/class;$malletdir/lib/mallet-deps.jar;$CLASSPATH"
```

**Important:** note that you now need to wrap the line in double-quotes, so that bash knows it is a string and doesn't end the command at the semi-colon.

Additionally, the paths need to be in UNIX style. To do this, change `-classpath $cp` on line 12 to `` -classpath `cygpath -pw $cp` ``.